# Display category and associated post listings

Tags: categories

I am having trouble figuring out a correct loop to display the following:

**Category Name:**

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3
- Post 4
- Post 5

See all posts in this category -->

Can anyone help me with a correct function or loop?

Comment: For a single category or for all?

Comment: I think I want for all.
So a page that would have a listing of categories like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $c) {
    echo '<h2>'. $c->name . '</h2>';
    $posts = get_posts(array( 'category' => $c->term_id, 'numberposts' => 5 ));
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo $post->post_title;
    }
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($c->term_id);?>">
        View all posts in <?php echo $c->name;?>
    </a>
    <?php
}
```